# Unwanted image glitch on can label after shrinkwrapping

Tags: modifiers

Blender newbie here trying to make a can render for a client to visualise a label design I'm working on. No matter what I try the rendered image has a weird image glitch in the label, even though that's not visible in any of the different viewport shading modes. The white areas of the label should be plain white with none of the grey/black smudges.

It happens after applying a shrinkwrap modifier to get it snug to the can. Without shrinkwrapping I can't get it snug, there's either a gap between the label and the can that casts a shadow, or, if there's no gap, parts of the label disappear inside the can despite the sides being perfectly vertical and the shape perfectly round. Any ideas on how to eradicate this would be welcome. Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As you're trying to project an image perfectly over the can, I think a better approach would be to use UV mapping to apply the image directly to the can.

Add a new material to the can called 'label' with the base colour set to your image texture. assign the label material to the faces you want to be the label.

Unwrap the Can's UVs using cylinder project,  then adjust as necessary.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The "parts of the label disappear inside the can" looks like Z-fighting. In layman terms, it's when two faces with the same alignment are in the same place and the software doesn't know which one to render as being closest to the camera, and instead renders a weird mix of both the faces.

You can move the Z-fighting faces apart by increasing the Offset value of the Shrinkwrap modifier.
[image]

If this causes a noticeable shadow, you could opt to disable the shadow for the label object.

First you have to set your preferred render engine, if you haven't already (Blender is set to the Eevee render engine by default.)

Go to the Properties window, select the Render Properties tab. Now select as the Render Engine either Eevee or Cycles.

**To remove the shadow of a single object in Eevee:**
Select the object, go to the properties window, select the Material Properties tab, go to Settings and change the Shadow Mode to None.

[image]

**To remove the shadow of a single object in Cycles:**
Select the object, go to the properties window, select the Object Properties tab, go to Visibility > Ray Visibility and uncheck the box Shadows.

[image]

As you stated, the Shrinkwrap with offset won't a perfect fit as when using UV-mapping to project the label image on the can object, as JeffUK suggested, but it might be sufficient. In any case, hope it helps : )

Comment: You could also double up on shrinkwrap modifiers, use one that affects all vertices that has an offset of .001, and then add only the top and bottom ring of vertices to a new vertex group, assign that to another shrinkwrap and set that offset to 0. That way the top and bottom are totally plastered but the rest is offset enough to avoid Z-fighting. You might have to insert a few edge-loops at the top and bottom to hold everything else off a tad.

Comment: Thanks guys. I tried most of these solutions and none of them worked. But I did happen opon a solution where I increased the circumference of the bezier circle by 1mm so it was slightly bigger than the can and then used the shrinkwrap modifier and it's worked. I think UV wrapping would be good too but I need to learn that method as it's not a quick thing to do for a newbie!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what others have suggested, you could also simply add a solidify modifier, since paper, is itself more that a 2D Plane.
[image]